# How to integrate Rocket.chat into Ionic 3 mobile app using iFrame?

Tags: ionic3, rocket.chat

We have our own rocket.chat server and is already embedded in our app via iframe but I need to get the user_id from our rocket.chat server during login and be saved in our mobile app's DB.

So I went to rocket.chat's documentation: https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/iframe-integration/authentication/ but don't know how to incorporate this in the ionic 3 app. Can someone assist me on this?

window.parent.postMessage({
  event: 'login-with-token',
  loginToken: 'your-token'
}, 'http://your.rocket.chat.url');